# Magento Exception error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9

After upgrade magento 1.9.1 to 1.9.2.4 I get this error in all category pages. Home page works fine and admin also.
The error is:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.status' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT MAX(e.min_price -(e.min_price/(1+(CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 2 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 4  THEN       0.2300 WHEN 5 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 6 THEN       0.2300  ELSE 0 END))*CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 2 THEN       0.2300  WHEN 4 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 5 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 6 THEN       0.2300   ELSE 0 END)+((e.min_price-(e.min_price/(1+(CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN        0.2300 WHEN 2 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 5 THEN        0.2300 WHEN 6 THEN       0.2300  ELSE 0 END))*CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 2 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 5 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 6 THEN       0.2300  ELSE 0 END))*CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 2 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 4  THEN       0.2300 WHEN 5 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 6 THEN       0.2300  ELSE 0  END) ) AS m_max_price FROM `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON   cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=3 AND  cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='47' WHERE  (e.status = 1) AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( e.customer_group_id = 0)  AND (e.min_price -(e.min_price/(1+(CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN        0.2300 WHEN 2 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 5 THEN        0.2300 WHEN 6 THEN       0.2300  ELSE 0 END))*CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1  THEN       0.2300 WHEN 2 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 5  THEN       0.2300 WHEN 6 THEN       0.2300  ELSE 0 END)+((e.min_price- (e.min_price/(1+(CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 2 THEN        0.2300 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 5 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 6 THEN        0.2300  ELSE 0 END))*CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 2  THEN       0.2300 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 5 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 6  THEN       0.2300  ELSE 0 END))*CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 1 THEN        0.2300 WHEN 2 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 4 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 5 THEN        0.2300 WHEN 6 THEN       0.2300  ELSE 0 END)  IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY  `m_max_price` DESC

Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/site/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/site/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/site/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT MAX(e.mi...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/site/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT MAX(e.mi...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/site/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /var/www/html/site/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Resource/Filter/Price.php(223): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /var/www/html/site/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Model/Filter/Price.php(198): Mana_Filters_Resource_Filter_Price->getMaxPriceOnCollection(Object(ManaPro_FilterSuperSlider_Model_Price), Object(GoMage_Navigation_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection))
#8 /var/www/html/site/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Model/Query.php(134): Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Price->getRangeOnCollection(Object(GoMage_Navigation_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection))
#9 /var/www/html/site/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Model/Filter/Price.php(123): Mana_Filters_Model_Query->getFilterRange('price')
#10 /var/www/html/site/app/code/local/ManaPro/FilterSuperSlider/Model/Price.php(55): Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Price->getMaxPriceInt()
#11 /var/www/html/site/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Block/Filter.php(88): ManaPro_FilterSuperSlider_Model_Price->getItemsCount()
#12 /var/www/html/site/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/manapro/filteradvanced/view.phtml(44): Mana_Filters_Block_Filter->getItemsCount()
#13 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/s...')
#14 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#15 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#16 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#17 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#19 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#21 /var/www/html/site/app/design/frontend/default/kallyas/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(56): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#22 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/s...')
#23 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#24 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#28 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#29 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#30 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#31 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172) : Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard-  >match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#32 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365):          Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#33 /var/www/html/site/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#34 /var/www/html/site/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#35 {main}
```

Any help please? I don't know how to proceed.

I run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE  COLUMN_NAME IN ('status') AND TABLE_SCHEMA='mydatabase'
```

It returns that  only this tables have this column:

```
TABLE_NAME
aw_arp_blocks
blog_post
blog_tag
catalog_product_flat_1
catalog_product_flat_3
cron_schedule
dataflow_batch_export
dataflow_batch_import
dataflow_import_data
downloadable_link_purchased_item
googlecheckout_notification
index_process
index_process_event
kallyas_blog
kallyas_blog_comment
m_seo_schema
m_seo_schema_flat
m_seo_schema_store
m_seo_schema_store_flat
m_seo_url
magemonkey_bulksync_export
magemonkey_bulksync_import
product_alert_price
product_alert_stock
recentreviewproducts
```

I can't find any e table. What should I check?

Comment: try to clean the cache and run indexer using command line

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that I already did it 2 times. Also I closed catalog category flat data and compilation.. The problem is still there. I have php 5.5 and mysqld 5.5 installed in centos 6.

Comment: does E table has status column ?

Comment: I run this query. SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('status') AND TABLE_SCHEMA='mydatabase'. No e table found. Check my post

Comment: Can you install a fresh version of 1.9.2.4 and compare its core_resource table versions to your installation? I have a feeling an upgrade script might've failed to run successfully. Do you have any non-vanilla modules that customize catalog/category? Are product pages or any other pages broken? Can you view category pages in admin?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your Stack Trace, it appears this request uses two different third party modules

```
Mana_Filters
ManaPro_FilterSuperSlider
```

It looks like the `ManaPro_FilterSuperSlide` extension initiates a query that doesn't work with your version of Magento.  This is either because

1. The extension just doesn't work with changes made between  1.9.1 and 1.9.2.4
2. Your update didn't complete for some reason

I'd start by disabling the `ManaPro_FilterSuperSlide` extension to see if it clears up the problem.

Comment: @G.G. Could you elaborate on your solution to this issue?  Did you just get rid of the ManaPro  module, upgrade it, or was it something else?  I'm experiencing the same issue with the same ManaDev module.

Answer (score 0):

By disabling in System -> Configuration -> Catalog the flat category and flat product, you can workaround and continue using an old version of Manadev